# How to write out HTML entity name (&nbsp;, &lt;, &gt;, etc)

Tags: html, entity

How would I write the entity name in HTML and not have it do its function? Example: I'm doing a tutorial and want to tell someone how to use the non-breaking space in their code (`&nbsp;`) So, how to actually write out "&" "n" "b" "s" "p" ";" but have it be fluid with no spaces?

Comment: you already did it here!

Comment: yes but it was done using stackoverflow's text editor. Apparently it doesn't recognize &nbsp;

Comment: @user2118228 He was able to do it here because on the SO website, putting any text between two backquotes causes it to display as is. For example... ``&nbsp;``

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `&amp;` instead of `&`
So `&nbsp;` will be `&amp;nbsp;`

Comment: Everybody said the same thing, but Accepted for simplicity.

Comment: The answer is incorrect, because the `pre` tag does not affect the interpretation of entity references.

Comment: Sorry. Really option with pre-tag is nonsense. So answer updated

Answer (score 4):

You will need to write out a part of the code, in this example, I'll use the ampersand. Instead of writing `&nbsp;`, write out the ampersand, `&amp;`, and then write nbsp;. Your final result should be `&amp;nbsp;`, which will display `&nbsp;` on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the HTML for the ampersand as in `&amp;nbsp;` which would display what you're looking for, i.e. &nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can be used to change the text of HTML element, below example adds non-blocking space entity character into `span` element.

```
<p>A common character entity used in HTML is the non-breaking space: <span id="myid"></span></p>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("myid").textContent= "&nbsp;";
  </script>
```