# force html to interpret " " as a nbsp text node

Tags: html, dom, whitespace, line-breaks

**[[Edited For Archive]]**

if you want to get a div to think it has a character in it, so that you can type in it while contenteditable == true on its parent element, see this link:
[type in empty divs while contenteditable = true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028406/insert-cursor-into-empty-divs-with-contenteditable)

**[[Original Question]]**

I am trying to insert a "`&nbsp;`" into my html but after parse it prints as a " "

I'm getting ---`<div>" some text"</div>`
I want ------->`<div>"&nbsp;some text"</div>` (where `&nbsp`; is a text node)

I have tried inserting 
`"&nbsp;"`and 
`String.fromCharCode(160)` and 
`document.createTextNode('\u00A0')` 
but no cigar

Dom experts please enlighten me

**edit:**
when i say I want it to be a `&nbsp;` node what I am trying to say is I want the `&nbsp` to appear in the dom in developer console. I have noticed that the behavior of the `" "` and `&nbsp;` are different as it seems the browser doesn't consider `" "` to contain any characters

**edit2**
Here is what my dom looks like on chrome developer tools[elements tab] for the two cases
[image: img]

just pretend the blocks are divs

the second div reports to have innerHTML = `"&nbsp;"`
whereas the first div doesnt even have an innerHTML property

and I know you're all gonna be like "thats what we said!" use `"&amp;nbsp;"`, but when I do that the browser prints the string `"&nbsp;"` instead of making a non break space

**edit 3** ok everyone stop trying to answer my stupid question. I am working with a contenteditable div and making a custom function that inserts a new div when the user presses enter. I construct an outerHTML string that contains the div tags with `&nbsp;` in the middle. The problem is html interprets `&nbsp;` as a `" "` unless you directly set `innerHTML = "&ampnbsp;"`. This is probably because when I made the string:

```
var nbsp = "&ampnbsp;";
string "<div>+nbsp+</div>
```

...so that I could edit the outerHTML, javascript reinterprets the `"&ampnbsp;"` to be a `" "`

so for a general case Maxime Lorant's and Mathew MacLean's answer will work... well and for mine but I had to do some extra work first.

am I crazy?

Thank you all for you help

Comment: There is no way to force browsers treat a character in a string as a text node. Please explain what you really want and specify whether you are referring to visual appearace (what should it really be?) or the DOM (exactly what tree do you want to get?).

Comment: check the recent edit

Comment: After the edit, the question is not any more about interpreting “ ” at all. If you want “&” to appear in the DOM, you write `&amp;` in HTML markup. There is then nothing special about the letters “nbsp”. But I doubt whether this is the real problem. Do you really want your page to show the five characters “&nbsp” (or the six characters “&nbsp;”)? It would normally make sense only on a page that *tells about HTML*.

Comment: You are right to assume I do not want the string "&nbsp" or "&nbsp;". I want the text node that tells the browser the string is not empty. It is my understanding (from my experimentation so I could be mistaken) that html treats `" "` and `&nbsp;` differently. I would like the browser to think that a div that contains the string `" "` is not empty. It seems to think the div is empty when it contains `" "`, but not when it contains `&nbsp;` - where `&nbsp;` is a `&nbsp;` and not a string

Comment: I'm working on some pictures to show you what I mean

Comment: You have accepted an answer about which you comment that it is not what you want. It would be best if you deleted this question and opened a new one that explains what you are doing and what you wish to achieve and what you have tried.

Comment: As this appears to be about `contenteditable` and browser behavior when implementing it as well as about scripting, you should present sufficient HTML and JavaScript to demonstrate what you mean (and describe user actions and browser reactions to them). Don’t forget then to tag the question with “javascript” too.

Comment: yes sorry I realize now that contenteditable was the problem, whereas I thought the problem was more generally about DOM manipulation

Comment: seems I cant delete the question as it already has answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sneaky little work around.

```
 <div>"&amp;nbsp;some text"</div>
```

This has also been answered here:
[How to write out HTML entity name (&nbsp;, &lt;, &gt;, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427713/how-to-write-out-html-entity-name-nbsp-lt-gt-etc)

Comment: I'm afraid it still parses as a space :(

Comment: hmm, that is interesting, but I dont want the string "&nbsp", I want the nonbreakspace text node that acts as a non empty string

Comment: I don't believe what you are asking for can be done. It will either display an empty space, or what I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a HTML entity, you need to escape the `&` with its own HTML entity: `&amp;`:

```
 &amp;nbsp;     ---> &nbsp;
 &amp;eacute;   ---> &eacute;
 ...
```

Comment: neither &amp;eacute; or &amp;nbsp; by themselves do the trick.
I am looking into HTML entities now in case I misunderstood your answer

Comment: I dont think so, I don't want the string "&nbsp;" but rather the text node that tells the browser the string is not empty