# type in empty divs while contenteditable = true?

Tags: javascript, dom, whitespace, contenteditable

why won't the cursor enter some of my divs when contenteditable is enabled?

also, why does my browser tell me there is nothing in the div when there is clearly a space character in it?!

```
var div = '<div> </div>'; 
div.innerHTML = undefined
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

contenteditable does not apply to empty elements, so you may want to insert a non-breaking-space character into the empty elements you want to be able to edit

the non-breaking-space `"&nbsp;"` will act as a character when left on its own, 
whereas a whitespace `" "` will only count as a character if placed after another character

`<div>" "</div>` ----------------> `innerHTML = undefined`
    `<div>"&nbsp;"</div>` --------> `innerHTML =`[image]

the gray box around `&nbsp;` means its an html character
so make sure you insert a `"&nbsp"` and not a `" "`

```
var nbsp = "&nbsp;",
    div = document.getElementById('id');
div.innerHTML = nbsp
```

jquery works too

```
var div = $('div#id')
div.html(nbsp1)
```