# Ascii character codes shown as text in browser

Tags: html, css, ascii

I run a website that has HTML tutorials on it. I am familiar with the use of ascii character codes like `&lt;` and `&gt;` when I am writing HTML tags on my website, but I want to show my users how to write their character codes like this. One of the ones I want to show them is a gap in HTML, represented by `&nbsp`, but whenever I type it on my HTML document it converts to a space, even though it is in the `<code>` tags. Is there an alternative that looks the same as `&nbsp`, but doesn't have any functionality? Maybe with CSS or HTML?

Comment: possibly  dupicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427713/how-to-write-out-html-entity-name-nbsp-lt-gt-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&lt;` and the like are not ASCII character codes, they're HTML entities.

And to show them, it's quite simple: escape the `&` by writing `&amp;` instead, so write `&amp;lt;` to show `&lt;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newbie in html, but try wrapping your code w/ <pre> </pre>

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you put it in your markup as

```
 &amp;nbsp;
```

It will give you what you want.