# How to know if &nbsp is a space or plain text?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I want to render.

```
Daniel &nbsp;
```

Above &nbsp is part of text I want to display. Let's say that's my surname.

Then I add two spaces which are replaced by Chrome browser to &nbsp. Now in the DOM we have:

```
Daniel&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Is there a way to differentiate in some way which `&nbsp;` is a plain text and which were inserted by browser? Let's assume that I have an editor and 'Daniel&nbsp' is my name. I can add spaces but, for example, I don't want to have any spaces at the end. In this case I'd regexp the whole content and remove each instance of `&nbsp;` but the first `&nbsp` is the one I'd like to keep, the one that was inserted by me manually earlier.

Comment: "*Then I add two spaces which are replaced by Chrome browser to `&nbsp;`.*" - how do you do that? If Chrome replaces your space with an entity, it should also replace the `&` with the `&amp;` entity.

Comment: Adding to @Bergi 's comment. `document.write("Daniel &nbsp;      ")` does not add any extra spaces. However the browser renders first of the streak of spaces and ignores the rest. So `document.write("firstname lastname")` will render the space between first and last name.

But `document.write("firstname           lastname")` will only render one space.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want, but this here may be the answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427713/how-to-write-out-html-entity-name-nbsp-lt-gt-etc)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
Daniel&nbsp&amp;nbsp;
```